# CiviCRM 4.6.8 compatible with Wordpress 4.3?

Tags: wordpress, error-page

CiviCRM 4.6.8
Wordpress 4.3
MySQL Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Datenbank-Client Version: libmysql - 5.5.44

I've imported contacts, added new contacts, without any problem.

Then I've added a rule for individuals in "Find and merge duplicate contacts". and added following rule: 
"Firstname Lastname"; 
"supervised";
"field=LastName"
"field=First Name". Saved and used the rule.

The message i've got was: **"DB Error: syntax error"**

Now I'm not able to add a new contact...

I've already tested this in the public demo and it didn't show an error-message.

Can someone help?

Here are the Error Details:

Sep 10 18:22:10  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array (
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

```
[code] => -2
[message] => DB Error: syntax error
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT 0 id1, 0 id2, 0 weight LIMIT 0 GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight)' at line 1]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT 0 id1, 0 id2, 0 weight LIMIT 0 GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight)' at line 1]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO dedupe (id1, id2, weight) SELECT 0 id1, 0 id2, 0 weight LIMIT 0 GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight) [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight)' at line 1]"]
```

)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't look like a Wordpress compatibility error.  It is, as you guessed, related to deduplication.

It sounds like you may not have a rule designated as your "Supervised" dedupe rule - or there's a problem with the rule you have designated as your "Supervised" rule.  Check to make sure you have a rule, and if you do, try changing it to the default Supervised dedupe rule.  That should clear your problem.  Then you can troubleshoot the dedupe rule itself.

Comment: thanks!

but... can I delete a reserved rule?

Comment: You can't delete a reserved rule - or at least you shouldn't!

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same problem on CiviCRM 4.7.... Creating an Individual contact resulted in "DB Error: syntax error" message on the front end. A custom de-dupe rule had been set as the "Supervised" rule, with just a single field from a multi-record custom data set. This naturally doesn't make sense as it's a multi-value data set and could have duplicate values for a single contact.

Setting the default "Name only" rule as the "Supervised" rule resolved the issue.

Lesson learned - do not use multi value custom data set fields in "Supervised" de-dupe rules.